# Should I use a property or an instance variable in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As stated in the title, should I refer to instance variables or the properties in viewDidLoad? I'd assume we should access through properties because "viewDidLoad" means "initialization is done, and all instance variables are initialized to their default values." Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, there really isn't any good reason to not use `@property`. You get all your getters and setters synthesized for you as well, which is quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, all the initialization is already happened in the code. ViewDidLoad can be used for additional initialization.

As per apple documentation:
"If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do so in the viewDidLoad method."

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to expand on your question a little bit more, and go into a little more detail of what exactly it is you're trying to achieve.

Whether you use a class property or an instance variable depends on what you want to do, personally I recommend sticking with @property (Class properties) for anything because they are fundamentally more functional, in terms of: you have getters and setters built for you to use and you don't have to make your own.

Comment: I already have those properties in place, but I wonder if I should access the instance variables of those properties (as in init methods) or should I use those properties directly. Looks like the universal consent is on using properties. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah you should just use properties directly as opposed to the instance variables of them. They are.... "safer"

Comment: @Gergy008 You may be mixing up your terminology a bit. `@property` is syntax for a *declared property* in Objective-C. The language doesn't provide a *class property* feature.

Answer (score 0):

> because "viewDidLoad" means "initialization is done, and all instance
>   variables are initialized to their default values

No, `viewDidLoad` means view is loaded into memory. This is not your `viewController`'s initialization method. Your `viewController`'s `init` or some method similar does mean initialization is done, and all instance variables are initialized to their default values

So you could use property if you like in `viewDidLoad`. I will always use it when it's appropriate.